# Updating legacy GLSL shaders to modern GLSL

Tags: glsl, shader

I'm trying to update an old *GLSL 120 shader* that I have and although most of it was of it was straightforward, it is the following I'm having trouble with:

**vertex shader:** gl_FrontSecondaryColor, gl_FrontColor

**fragment shader:** gl_Color, gl_SecondaryColor

The problem is that I haven't been able to find ample alternatives for anything 3.x and above.

**For example:**
The replacement for **gl_FragColor** is to create

```
layout (location = 0) out vec4 fragColor;
```

But for the other above stated, how exactly would they be handled?

Comment: OpenGL graphic pipeline has changed a lot, have a look at https://learnopengl.com/#!Advanced-OpenGL/Advanced-GLSL

Comment: @MrKiwi Yes, it has changed a lot, but what I'm referring to is what the modern equivalency is, much like you don't use gl_FragColor, gl_ProjectViewMatrix, etc anymore. Instead you create your own uniforms and variables.

Answer (score 1):

> gl_FrontSecondaryColor, gl_FrontColor

These are just vertex shader outputs. They're not special in any way.

> gl_Color, gl_SecondaryColor

These are magic fragment shader things that effectively perform conditional logic within your shader. They do front/back face testing, and then fetch the front or back color of the appropriate kind.

So if you're doing two-sided rendering, you would have to do the test *yourself*. The VS would output a front and back value, and the FS would input both, but pick one to use depending on the triangle's facing. The [built-in `gl_FrontFace` variable](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#System_inputs) tells if the current face is front or back. You use that to select which input value to use.

And if you're not doing two-sided rendering... you don't care. You just have a VS output and an FS input.